# update array data to database inside looping

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I face a problem with update more then one value with the same name to database.

```
//while loop
{
<input  name="exists[]" value='$row1[Status_Name]'></input>
}
```

bellow are how I update the data to database

```
if (isset($_POST["updsts"]))
{
    $gid = $_POST["id"];

    $sqlq = "SELECT * FROM orderstatus WHERE Status_Group = '$gid'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlq);

    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($rowcount == 0)
    echo "No records found";        
    else 
    {
        $x = '0';

        while( $x<$rowcount)
        {
            $stsname = $_POST["exists[$x]"];

            $sqlu = "UPDATE orderstatus SET 
            Status_Name = '$stsname'
            WHERE Status_Group = '$gid'";

            $x++;
        }
}
```

My `$row1[Status_Name]` will show all the status_name inside a table.

Comment: (1)Please align your code. (2)Please add `php` tag.

Comment: Are you saying Status_Group and Status_Name has  1 to many relationship?  e.g.  Lets say gid = 'A'.  There can be many Status_Name with gid='A'.

Comment: yes ,you are right.

Comment: Your update SQL will update all rows with a particular Status_Group.  So lets say you have 5 rows  of table with Status_Group = 'A', your current  SQL will update all 5 rows.  If there is just one row for particular Status_Group and Status_Name, (e.g. Status_Group = 'A' and Status_Name = 'X' ), the SQL needs  further `WHERE` clause.  Add one more `WHERE` clause.  `AND Status_Name = '$row1[Status_Name]`.

Comment: @Nguaial ya,just now I tested many way to do it,but keep facing the problem with the data will update all or cannot get the post function.But now I can doing it using my own way.

Comment: One tip:  Make sure the SQL is working properly.  So work within MySQL before moving onto PHP/HTML.

Comment: ok,sure. Thankyou for remind

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the post array key:

```
foreach ($_POST['exists'] as $val) {
  // Do your updates here
}
```

Additionally, this code has a lot of other serious problems you should be aware of.

- You're not escaping any data used in the context of HTML.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data you're concatenating into HTML.  Without this, you risk creating invalid HTML as well as potential security issues with injected scripts.
- You're not escaping any data used in your queries!  As it stands right now, pretty much anyone can do whatever they want with your database data.  Automated bots hit these sort of scripts and exploit them all the time.  Use parameterized queries, always.  Never concatenate data into the context of a query!
- There's no need for this select and then update loop.  Just use one update.

Comment: sorry,I'm not so clear how to use this code.May you explain further?Thankyou